# Rancher Setup RKE With Signed Certs

Tags: kubernetes, rancher

After some research I have found that is possible to create csr's using the rke client as stated in this guide:
https://rancher.com/docs/rke/latest/en/cert-mgmt/

Would it be possible to deploy a RKE cluster using Rancher 2.x with signed certs or does this have to be done using the RKE client?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i checked in this [github issue](https://github.com/rancher/rancher/issues/14674)

as mentioned by @deniseschannon in above link

> In Rancher 2.2 and RKE 0.2.0, we've only added the ability to bring your own certs to clusters created with the RKE CLI.
>
> https://rancher.com/docs/rke/latest/en/installation/certs/#generating-certificate-signing-requests-csrs-and-keys

---

Additionaly you can check this rancher link about [**Certificates**](https://www.rancher.co.jp/docs/rke/latest/en/installation/#certificates)

> Available as of v0.2.0
>
> By default, Kubernetes clusters require certificates and RKE auto-generates the certificates for all the Kubernetes services. RKE can also use custom certificates for these Kubernetes services.
>
> By default, Kubernetes clusters require certificates and RKE auto-generates the certificates for all cluster components. You can also use [custom certificates](https://www.rancher.co.jp/docs/rke/latest/en/installation/certs/). After the Kubernetes cluster is deployed, you can [manage these auto-generated certificates](https://www.rancher.co.jp/docs/rke/latest/en/cert-mgmt/#certificate-rotation).

---

Based on that I would say it's possible only with RKE.

Comment: I haven't had the chance to test due to workload at the moment, but I will mark this answered as its is worth trying when I can get the chance.